# How to access Instance attributes from OpsWorks chef cookbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

AWS provides way to access instance attributes from opsworks chef recipe [OpsWorks Instance Attributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/attributes-json-opsworks-instance.html#attributes-json-opsworks-instance-host).

There is an attribute "node["opsworks"]["instance"]["private_ip"]".  How can i access this IP from recipe in chef 12 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the docs on this page: [Moving Stack Settings from Attributes to Data Bags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/attributes-to-data-bags.html)

> In Chef 11.10 and earlier versions for Linux, stack settings are available as Chef attributes and are accessed through the Chef node object...
>
> ...In Chef 12 Linux, stack settings are available as Chef data bags and are accessed only through Chef search.

You can see examples in the [Instance Data Bag (aws_opsworks_instance) page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/data-bag-json-instance.html) and all available variables in the [AWS OpsWorks Stacks Data Bag Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/data-bags.html)

In your case you'd do something like this:

```
instance = search("aws_opsworks_instance").first
private_ip = instance["private_ip"]
```